# Looping with iterator vs temp object gives different result graphically (Libgdx/Java)

Tags: iterator, render, libgdx

I've got a particle "engine" whom I've implementing a Pool system to and I've tested two different ways of rendering every Particle in a list. Please note that the Pooling really doesn't have anything with the problem to do. I just followed a tutorial and tried to use the second method when I noticed that they behaved differently.

The first way:

```
            for (int i = 0; i < particleList.size(); i++) {
            Iterator<Particle> it = particleList.iterator();
            while (it.hasNext()) {
                Particle p = it.next();
                if (p.isDead()){
                    it.remove();
                }

                p.render(batch, delta);
            }
        }
```

Which works just fine. My particles are sharp and they move with the correct speed.

The second way:

```
            Particle p;
        for (int i = 0; i < particleList.size(); i++) {
            p = particleList.get(i);
            p.render(batch, delta);

            if (p.isDead()) {
                particleList.remove(i);
                bulletPool.free(p);
            }

        }
```

Which makes all my particles blurry and moving really slow!

The render method for my particles look like this:

```
    public void render(SpriteBatch batch, float delta) {
    sprite.setX(sprite.getX() + (dx * speed) * delta * Assets.FPS);
    sprite.setY(sprite.getY() + (dy * speed) * delta * Assets.FPS);
    ttl--;
    sprite.setScale(sprite.getScaleX() - 0.002f);

    if (ttl <= 0 || sprite.getScaleX() <= 0)
        isDead = true;

    sprite.draw(batch);
}
```

Why do the different rendering methods provide different results?

Thanks in advance

Comment: what data structure is particleList? If it is a linked-list then I would say its expected behavior because you are accessing it via index.

Answer (score 2):

You are mutating (removing elements from) a list while iterating over it.  This is a classic way to make a mess.

The `Iterator` must have code to handle the delete case correctly.  But your index-based `for` loop does not.  Specifically when you call `particleList.remove(i)` the `i` is now "out of sync" with the content of the list.  Consider what happens when you remove the element at index 3: 'i' will increment to 4, but the old element 4 got shuffled down into index 3, so it will get skipped.

I assume you're avoiding the `Iterator` to avoid memory allocations.  So, one way to side-step this issue is to reverse the loop (go from `particleList.size()` down to 0).  Alternatively, you can only increment `i` for non-dead particles.